# Why is the version of v$timezone_file not the same of DBMS_DST.get_latest_timezone_version?

Tags: oracle

I am having an Oracle problem with a dump import (impdp). The error I get "ORA-39002: invalid operation" has no other information in the logs. Online I find some mention of file permissions, but that doesn't seem to be a problem.

I suspect that a patch that I installed went wonky.

After investigating, I found something that looked odd.

I would think that these queries would essentially return the same.

```
SELECT * FROM v$timezone_file;
SELECT DBMS_DST.get_latest_timezone_version FROM   dual;
```

However, first one results in version 31 and the second one 40.

```
FILENAME                VERSION     CON_ID
-------------------- ---------- ----------
timezlrg_31.dat              31          0

GET_LATEST_TIMEZONE_VERSION
---------------------------
                         40
```

Can this be correct? And if not how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function [doesn't seem to be documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/arpls/DBMS_DST.html#GUID-4C6AC264-846F-4F68-BD8A-B36BCA545F5D), but according to [a usually reliable source](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/update-database-time-zone-file#getting-the-latest-time-zone-file) it shows the latest available version of the timezone file (as of the Oracle release or latest patch level you have installed), not what you are actually using.

[From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html?source=%3Aem%3Anw%3Amt%3A%3Arc_wwmk180514p00061%3Ansl100768561&source=%3Aem%3Anw%3Amt%3A%3Arc_wwmk180514p00061%3Ansl100768561#GUID-B0ACDB2E-4B49-4EB4-B4CC-9260DAE1567A):

> **Note:** Each Oracle Database release includes a time zone file that is current at the time of the release and a number of older version files. Between Oracle Database releases, new time zone file versions may be provided in patch sets or individual patches to reflect the changes in transition rules for various time zone regions. Older time zone file versions allow you to run upgraded databases without a need to immediately upgrade the time zone file to the most current version.

It appears that your release/patch level includes files up to version 40, but you have not upgraded beyond version 31. So you may want to consider upgrading to the latest available file.

If you think the version you are using is causing your import failure, you could perhaps try [setting `ORA_TZFILE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-805AB986-DE12-4FEA-AF56-5AABCD2132DF) in your environment, to match the database version. No idea if that will actually help...

The error you are getting does usually relate to permissions, for the data or log directories, but there would normally be other messages in the error stack to give you more of an idea what might be wrong.